# How can I open an entire folder full of images in VLC using the Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, vlc-media-player

Recently I've been trying to replace Microsoft's PowerPoint Viewer program on a few Windows computers in my workplace that display a powerpoint full of images to library patrons, including library events, etc. I wanted to see if I could simply export the powerpoint as a powerpoint show and then put that in the Startups folder, but unfortunately I don't think I'm going to get very far reeducating staff.

As a possible alternative solution, I've wondered if I can get staff to simply export a series of images to a folder which VLC will run on startup. I've found that I can access PNG files, but unfortunately opening a folder with VLC will, by default, only open videos. Is there a way I can change this behavior to also open images? Or alternatively is there another way I can tell VLC to open a folder of images without manually creating some kind of playlist file?

Comment: Why VLC? IrfanView will move through the contents of a a folder using a key press, such as left and right arrows or page up & down.

Comment: The slides need to swap automatically. These displays will not have a keyboard attached.

Comment: Which IrfanView can do... see answer, which I'll add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your intended use, [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) seems like a much better tool. Both VLC and IrfanView are excellent free applications, with overlapping functionality, but VLC is inteded more for video media and IrfanView for still images. In the Slideshow mode, shown below, you can choose individual files, a whole folder, or load a list from a text file (which can also be created within the dialog). Slide advancement can be at any specified rate, from a fraction of a second to hours (or by key press or mouse, which you would not use). It can be set to loop continuously, as you would in kiosk mode.

After installing IrfanView (about 4 MB in size), and optional plugins, press <kbd>w</kbd> to open the Slideshow setup dialog, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to run it from a list. Oh, and the plugin *Slideshow.exe* can be installed to make the slideshow into a executable file or into a screensaver (.scr) file, so IrfanView does not need to be installed on the target machine.

[image: IrfanView Slideshow Configuration dialog]

Comment: Is there a way I can tell it to automatically run a slideshow of a folder from the command line? It'd make it easier for staff to just put image files in a folder, then for Irfanview to automatically do the rest on startup.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me here. I want to avoid having to make staff create a .SCR file (the library staff consists of older, less computer-literate users, and I'd like to avoid retraining them if possible) and instead have Irfanview open a folder full of images and automatically cycle through them, with the folder being on our server, so that staff merely needs to drop images into the folder and restart the display computers. I tried searching for the answer myself and came across the /slideshow command argument, however the /reloadonloop argument doesn't seem to be looping the show.

Comment: You could create a batch file that lists all the image files, e.g. `dir /b /s >> c:\temp\list.txt`, and then start IrfanView from the command line, using the options `/slideshow=list.txt` . See http://irfanview.helpmax.net/en/overview/command-line-options/

Comment: I was testing it earlier using the /slideshow argument with a folder and for some reason /reloadonloop wasn't making it loop, but I think using a full pathname fixed it. I guess I have my solution then

Answer (score 0):

> Is there away I can tell VLC to open a folder of images without manually creating some kind of playlist file?

Yes. You can use the [VLC `--one-instance` and `--playlist-enqueue` options](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) to load individual images into a playlist dynamically. The drawbacks to this approach are:

- You need a script to cycle through a directory and load these images initially.
- Looping doesn't seem to work well with this method.

If you are set on using a media player for this (as opposed to ex. IrfanView), [MPV](https://mpv.io/) may be worth considering. MPV can load a directory full of images and play them back as follows:

```
mpv "C:\path\to\images"
```

Windows builds of MPV are available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/files/) if you want to give it a try.

**Caveats**

One issue to be aware of with MPV is that while it will play a folder of images, there currently doesn't appear to be a dedicated option to select the time an image is displayed (which defaults to 1 second).

However, you can delay each image by playing an additional, external, silent audio file of a fixed length ex.:

```
mpv "C:\path\to\images" --audio-file="C:\path\to\10_second_silence.ext"
```

**Additional Options**

Other MPV options that might be useful for a "slideshow" likely include:

- `--loop-playlist` - Loop the current playlist indefinitely.
- `--shuffle` - Play back any media files (e.g. images) in a playlist in a randomized order.
- `--no-border` - Remove the border around the playback window. Note that MPV has a basic set of on-screen controls that do not rely on a standard Windows border (ex. to close the window).
- `--fullscreen` - Play any media files back with the playback window maximized.

**References**

Documentation for MPV is available [here](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/) (Stable) and [here](https://mpv.io/manual/master/) (Master).